# 80's sci fi movie where the hero falls into a trash dump

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It seems like an 80's science fiction film and all I remember is that the hero is dropped out of a futuristic flying garbage ship into a large garbage wasteland, where he is saved and nursed by dwellers of the dump.

Saw I'm 99 or 2000 in a TV store playing.I saw only 5 minutes of it so that's why it's hard to find cause details are limited.

A filing ship flies over a waste dump and either dumps the hero out with the trash or escapes the ship and lands in the landfill.

A landfill people find him and offer refuge, I can't remember if authorities raid the landfill community hideouts looking for our hero or not.

Movie has a masters of the universe feel to it.
But the big thing I remember are the landfill scavenging people and the man dumped out of a flying ship used to dump garbage. Seems like it was close to start of movie when the hero was dumped or jumped out of ship into landfill.

Film was American English a pallet of desert colors and red. I do remember the hero had to try and get back onto a ship to get out of wasteland he was dropped in.

Comment: Are the "dwellers of the dump" particularly stupid?  [Idiocracy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/) springs to mind (Although it's not an 80's flick)

Comment: Add more details like when you watched it, in which language, whether it was in black & white or color, names of hero/heroine (or their resemblance)...

Comment: Kindly don't submit your edits as an answer and it will be better if you can do it from single account only. Refer [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to know how to merge multiple accounts.

Comment: That's a whole lot of detail from only seeing 5 minutes of it...

Answer (score 5):

This is [**Soldier**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120157/) (1998) with Kurt Russell

> A soldier is dumped on a waste disposal planet and lives among a community of crash survivors on the planet and takes it upon himself to defend his new home when genetic engineered soldiers are ordered to eliminate the crash survivors.